# Can I change a std::string, which has been assigned to a std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, string-view

I just knew that C++17 introduced `std::string_view`. It doesn't hold any string, instead, it points to a string. If so, I'm confused by the case below:

```
std::string str = "abc";
std::string_view strV = str;
std::cout << strV << std::endl;
str = "1";
std::cout << strV << std::endl;
```

I just tried the piece of code on some c++17 compiler online, here is the output:

```
abc
1c
```

Obviously, `1c` is not what I expected.

So does it mean that we shouldn't change the string which has been assigned to a `std::string_view`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you did expect, but expecting anything in particular from this code is wrong, as its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: A view is that a view on the underlying data, if you change the underlying data what your view "sees" will also be changed. And since std::string can reallocate you can suddenly have a view on memory that is no longer valid. I think the documentation on string_view is quite clear on this.

Comment: You might want to watch [Just enough string_view to hang ourselves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwP4YCP_0q0) from cppcon 2018. Specifically this time point : https://youtu.be/xwP4YCP_0q0?t=793

Comment: I recommend you avoid using `std::string_view` in ways that allow the underlying string data to change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't, as it is fragile.
Anyway:

You may change the data behind a reference (a `std::string_view` is a reference to a string-segment, not to a string like `std::string`, consisting of start and length), just be aware that you did and how you did it.
Though refrain from deallocating it, using dangling references is bad.

`std::string` doesn't reallocate if the new value fits the current capacity and there is no move-assignment, or both are in SBO-mode.
In your example, all three are true.

The only problem is that the data beyond the string-terminator is indeterminate after the assignment, though it is not explicitly overwritten, thus staying `c` for efficiency.

Comment: While technically true, I wouldn't make an habit of exploiting this thing, especially with assignment, as there's multiple subtle things that may break this delicate balance (e.g. changing `str = "1"` to `str = something_that_returns_a_string()` will trigger move assignment, that will break this unless SSO is triggered, or `str = another_str` which will or won't break depending on size/capacity/SSO).

Comment: Yes basically the only changes I would consider fine are inplace changes like `str[1] = '1'`. Assigning a new value is certainly implementation defined and so I would not rely on it

Comment: @MatteoItalia Made that warning more prominent.

Answer (score 6):

A string_view stores a pointer to the start of the string and the length of the string.
Replacing the text stored by the string invalidates both of them, since this might lead to a different length and/or a different storage location.

So yes changing the string invalidates the string_view.

Comment: But the string isn't replaced, only its value. In cases like this, the details matter.

Comment: Yes this was slightly unclear. I do mean the stored string value. So essentially the moment you assign a new string value you are invalidating the string (unless there is SSO, which you really should not rely on)

Answer (score 3):

`std::string_view` is just fancy form of const reference to buffer containing characters. This buffer can be manged by `std::string` or can be string literal or some array of `char`.

As a result use of `std::string_view` must not extend beyond of lifetime of this buffer. In your example buffer was modified before string view was used leading to undefined behavior.

Now since most compilers are implementing Small String Optimization, your example didn't crash. In more general cases this code will fail miserably.

Note that `std::string_view` was introduced mainly to more effectively parse some data in long strings which are not modified.